# divide NetLogo world into several random parts

Tags: patch, netlogo

I am trying to create a number of groups of agents on the NetLogo world. I hope each of the groups is located at a specific area without overlap. As I can think of, the easies way to achieve this might be dividing the world into several parts first. Each part consists of a number of patches (say 100 + random 10, which I can set) and is colored with a unique color. Then ask the newly created turtles to move to patches with different colors. 
Could anybody tell me how to achieve this or give any suggestion, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What size and shape should the parts be? Should they come up right next to each (borders touching) or be completely separate?

Comment: The size should be set by the designer. But it doesn't have to be an exact number -- can be a range or a random number (e.g. 100 + random 10). You pick up patches random in the world (of course they should be adjacent to each other). The shape thus is defined by the size. The parts should be border-touching, and all parts should occupy the world completely.

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is to grow different regions. For example:

```
to grow-regions [ num-regions ]
  let region-num 0
  ask n-of num-regions patches [
    set pcolor item region-num base-colors
    set region-num region-num + 1
  ]
  while [ any? patches with [ pcolor = black ] ] [
    ask patches with [ pcolor != black ] [
      ask neighbors with [ pcolor = black ] [ set pcolor [ pcolor ] of myself ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Note that this can draw at most 14 different regions (since that's the number of base colors).

This results in regions like so:

[image: Regions]

Edit: Misread your comment. Obviously, this doesn't let you control the size of the regions, but the average size will be `count patches / num-regions`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This's almost what I want. I can improve based on this. I'm not quite sure how you set the size of the regions. What exactly my questions is what the order for each regions to run the while loop is. It seems that each of them run the loop once (with random order in each run), and when all of them finish, each of them run the loop again...

Comment: Try running the code with the speed set low and continuous view updates. You'll be able to see how each patch as it gets colored. Put in a `print` statement right after the `while` line so you can see when each iteration begins.