# Divide world into equal parts

Tags: netlogo

---

***Edited***

Removed duplicated question. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598499/generate-rivers-with-random-size-and-location) for the removed question.

---

**2)** I want to ***divide the world*** into 9 or 16 parts (***with the same size***). I want the world to be several squares (either 3x3 or 4x4). I found something that is on the right track here at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698008/divide-netlogo-world-into-several-random-parts) and with @Bryan Head's code, I can generate something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXz2S.jpg). But I don't want the size to be random, I want all areas to have the same size.

```
; Dividing the world randomly into 14 parts.
ca
let region-num 0
ask n-of 14 patches [
  set pcolor item region-num base-colors
  set region-num region-num + 1
  ]
while [ any? patches with [ pcolor = black ] ] [
  ask patches with [ pcolor != black ] [
     ask neighbors with [ pcolor = black ] [ set pcolor [ pcolor ] of myself ]
  ]
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: please don't ask the same question twice

Comment: @Jumboman First of all: thank you for your kind help. Second, I edited the post and removed the first question and instead refers to my other post instead. I'm sorry for double-posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for point 2: you could use

```
ask patches with [pxcor < 3 and pycor < 3]
```

to get all patches in a corner. You can expand on this to divide the map into parts.

edit to expand on my comment: try the code below.

```
to test
  resize-world 0 8 0 8
  let x 3
  let y 3
  let col 5
  while [y <= 9][
    while [x <= 9][
      ask patches with [pxcor < x and pxcor >= x - 3 and pycor < y and pycor >= y - 3][
        set pcolor col
      ]
      set x x + 3
      set col col + 10
    ]
    set x 3
    set y y + 3
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jumboman! I tried that earlier, however, I'd prefer something that is independent of the size of the world, since I will have to change that later on. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough in my original post. Do you have any suggestions on how to make the code ***adjust according to the size of the world***?

Comment: you can use max-pxcor / max-pycor and divide it by 3 or 4. obviously the world size should then be a multiple of those numbers or the world won't be equal

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code you can try. it doesnt use the `max-pxcor max-pycor` but I'm sure you can apply that yourself